# sed to insert blank lines between sets?

Tags: sed

Can I use sed to insert a carriage return between lines starting with a new beginning token?
For example, if input file is:

```
12 line1
12 line2 
12 line3
13 line4
13 line5
```

is there a way to use sed to generate the output that inserts a blank line?

```
12 line1
12 line2 
12 line3

13 line4
13 line5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'N;/^(\S+\s).*\n\1/!{P;s/.*\n/\n/};P;D' file
```

Append the following line.

If the first fields of the current line and the appended line do not match, print the first line and replace it by a newline.

In either case, print/delete the first line and repeat.

---

Alternative:

```
sed -E ':a;h;n;H;x;/^(\S+\s).*\n\1/!{z;p};x;ba' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use this command to insert a blank line between lines starting with the token "12":

```
sed '/^12/{p;d}' input.txt
```

This command will print the input file with a blank line inserted between each line that starts with "12".